# Как восстановить выделение текста в EditText после выхода из ActionMode

Tags: android, android-edittext

В терминологии могу путаться. В Android совсем недавно.
Создаю обычный проект с BlankActivity.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package pro1c.net.testactionmode;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Запускаю на выполнение. Выделяю текст и выхожу из ActionMode.

[image: Запускаю на выполнение. Выделяю текст и выхожу из ActionMode.]

Выделение пропадает. Курсор устанавливается туда где раньше был конец выделения.

[image: Выделение пропадает. Курсор устанавливается туда где раньше был конец выделения.]

**Вопрос**: Как сохранить выделение после выхода из ActionMode?

Я попробовал решить так:

Создал SelectionEditText.java (Был найден тут https://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ime/latinime/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/inputmethod/latin/tutorial/SelectionEditText.java) Он позволяет поймать событие изменения выделения текста.

**SelectionEditText.java**

```
package pro1c.net.testactionmode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SelectionEditText extends EditText {
    private SelectionListener mSelectionListener = null;

    private int mOldSelStart = 0;
    private int mOldSelEnd = 0;

    public SelectionEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SelectionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SelectionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setSelectionListener(SelectionListener selectionListener) {
        mSelectionListener = selectionListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

        if (mSelectionListener != null) {
            mSelectionListener.onSelectionChanged(this, mOldSelStart, mOldSelEnd, selStart, selEnd);
        }

        mOldSelStart = selStart;
        mOldSelEnd = selEnd;
    }

    public static interface SelectionListener {
        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEditText editText, int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd,
                                       int selStart, int selEnd);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
Немного подправляю чтобы он использовал класс SelectionEditText

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <pro1c.net.testactionmode.SelectionEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**
Имплементирую ActionMode.Callback и SelectionEditText.SelectionListener
При завершении ActionMode устанавливаю локальную переменную destroyActionMode в true.
А дальше когда происходит попытка изменить выделение текста, проверяю эту переменную, и возвращаю выделение обратно на старые позиции.

```
package pro1c.net.testactionmode;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionMode.Callback,SelectionEditText.SelectionListener{

    SelectionEditText editText;
    private boolean destroyActionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (SelectionEditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(this);
        editText.setSelectionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        destroyActionMode = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEditText editText, int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd, int selStart, int selEnd) {
        if (destroyActionMode){
            editText.setSelection(oldSelStart,oldSelEnd);
            destroyActionMode = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я сделал? Что-то подсказывает мне, что решение не совсем изящное.
Есть ли другой способ сохранить выделение текста после отключения ActionMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это стандартный use case, когда после выхода из action mode выделение сбрасывается, так задумано.
Если по какой-то причине это надо обойти, я бы просто использовал свой ActionMode.Callback, где в onCreateActionMode() сохранял состояние выделения, а в onDestroyActionMode() восстанавливал.
Так было бы проще и нагляднее.

Comment: Сначала было обрадовался, но в onDestroyActionMode() выделение еще прежнее. Сброс происходит где-то позже, уже после выхода из onDestroyActionMode

Comment: Тогда только свой потомок от EditText, как и сделано. Больше идей нет.